Converting double type to binary in C++
I have a task to test various pseudo random number generators in C++, using NIST-800-22. NIST test suite requires me to convert generated numbers and store them in binary format, for integers it wasnt that hard. Problem comes with generators generating only double type numbers.
I know double type is stored as a floating point with IEEE 754 standard, but I dont really know how to convert it to binary. ChatGPT suggested me some solutions, but converted numbers look like this 0011111111100100001010110110010110100000000000000000000000000000, it doesnt look random and I think it interferes too much with stored data.
My question is, is there a way to read raw generated binary data, or how to get it?
Code Chat suggested me to use:
std::string doubleToBinary(double num) {
    uint64_t rawBits;
    std::memcpy(&rawBits, &num, sizeof(double));
    std::bitset<64> binary(rawBits);
    return binary.to_string();
}


It is unclear what is meant by "store" and what the purpose of storing is. In principle, you have no conversion at all to perform, floating-point is a binary representation.

No matter what you do or how you solve it, the binary representation is not portable. It's not guaranteed by the C++ specification to be IEEE 754. And IEEE 754 doesn't specify possible endianness.

"ChatGPT suggested me..." Chatgpt hardly ever gives correct answer for real programming question. It's often a marketing gimmick.

"it doesnt look random" which distribution/criteria do you use, float has mantissa and exponent, choosing from float range would not be the same as choosing both within their respective range.

As for the problem of the numbers not looking "random", how are you generating the numbers? Can you please [edit] your question to show us a simplified [mre]?

@Someprogrammerdude you are off track. Looks like he creates some own random generator, which he wishes to test with NIST-800-22 test suite. His problem is to feed data to this test suites (I think it accepts data in binary representation of floating points to avoid conversion problems between binary and decimal representation). Question is how to reliably feed data to this test suite.

The problem here is not about double-to-binary conversion, it's about providing data in the correct format for a NIST test suite. And that is where additional clarity is needed.

IMO you should add to your code static_assert(std::numeric_limits<double>::is_iec559)  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559  and static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::little). If static assertions are passing then your code should be fine. Otherwise you have to rewrite your code.

@user12002570: If you're not using 4o, you're using the "also ran" version of ChatGPT.  Also, much like Stack Overflow, it helps if you know how to ask good questions.  Garbage in, garbage out.

I'm not familiar with the NIST test suite, but given the structure of the double-precision binary format, you shouldn't necessarily expect a random distribution of bits for a given random distribution of doubles.  It will depend entirely on what kind of distribution of doubles you have.  A uniform distribution on [0, 1], for example, will have very predictable 0 bits in the exponent.

Floating point numbers do not have a random linear distribution (since not ALL floating point numbers are exactly representable) , you would need to generate random mantissa AND a random exponent to get a good distribution.

Please read, or skim, NIST SP 800-22. I see nothing in there that even suggests that any of the tests accept any kind of floating point number at all. All those tests are for measuring randomness in what are defined as binary sequences. It appears that we have three answers so far, each irrelevant to the underlying question which has a flawed premise.

The problem consists of two parts:

Converting a floating point number to an array of bytes
Converting the obtained bytes into NIST compatible format.

The later part needs more context to be answered. But the first part has to address 3 platform portability issues:

IEEE-754 conformity
Endian-ness
Floating point size and padding bits.

The 3rd problem above needs platform specific knowledge, and cannot be addressed in a generic answer.
The 1st and 2nd problem as shall be seen can be partially addressed for major platforms(but special cases are left outside).
I will provide a partial implementation for a function template that converts intrinsic numeric data into a byte array:
#include <bit>         //C++20
#include <ranges>      //C++20
#include <utility>
#include <array>       //C++11
#include <type_traits> //C++11

template<typename numeric>
requires std::is_arithmetic_v<numeric>
constexpr auto to_network_bytes(numeric const n){
    using namespace std;
    auto byte_array =
         bit_cast<array<byte/*C++17*/, sizeof(n)>>(n);
    if constexpr(endian::native==endian:: little)
        return byte_array;
    else if constexpr(endian::native==endian::big)
        ranges::reverse(byte_array);
    else  // mixed endian
        /*handle endian-ness*/;
    
    return byte_array;    
};

For integral types, mixed endian case can have a generic byte order detection and reordering algorithm too. But I skip that here.
As mentioned in comments, IEEE-754 conformity can be checked through std::numeric_limits<numeric>::is_iec559(from C++98 <limits>), provided that std::is_floating_point_v<numeric>(from <type_traits>). But if the test fails(false value), platform specific conversion must be applied to the byte array resulting from the above function.
In the end another conversion to NIST format would be required.

Just a little advice.
Suppose that you generate random numbers with double type in the range [a, b), you can map them to [0, 1) first. Then obtain its binary format using memcpy, you can extract the trialing 52 bits (the fraction part of the format) and inputs them to NIST-800-22.

However, this method do not use all full 64 bits.
